# python Tornado handler IO blocks entire server networking

Tags: python, python-3.x, nginx, tornado

I'm implementing REST api with tornado, and want it to be non-blocking.

Currently, issue-related code goes like this:

```
class ReprsHandler(web.RequestHandler):
    async def get(self, name):

        db = await dbf.create_handler()

        if 'id' in list(self.request.query_arguments.keys()):
            db_future = asyncio.ensure_future(db.get_repr(name, self.get_query_argument('id')))
        else:
            db_future = asyncio.ensure_future(db.get_reprs(name))

        result = await db_future
        response = result.toSerializedStream()

        self.set_status(HTTPStatus.OK)
        self.write(response)
        self.set_header('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
        self.finish()


class App(object):
    def __init__(self, loop):
        self.server_app = web.Application(
            handlers=[
                (r"/api/v1/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/reprs", ReprsHandler),
            ]
        )

def main():
    AsyncIOMainLoop().install()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    app = App(loop)
    server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app.server_app, max_body_size=config['max_upload_size'], max_buffer_size=config['max_upload_size'])
    server.bind(config['server_port'])
    server.start()

    loop.run_forever()
```

Simple code, but the data is quite large, so that it takes about 3~4 minutes to send all.

I expected handler's logic and networking IO both to be non-blocking, but it blocks the server network while sending data as response. logic is fine. They don't block other requests.

Details:

- This code runs on docker, ubuntu 16.04, implemented with python 3.5.
- The server is using nginx as port proxy.

What could be a problem? I have no idea whats making this problem.

Comment: What does `result.toSerializedStream()` do? Since you mention that "data is quite large", I'm assuming the `result` variable is the data and it is large. So, if `.toSerializedStream()` does any CPU bound task on a large data, then that might be the reason for blocking.

Comment: The method uses pickle dumps to generate serialized string of data object, but the logic's time cost is not that huge as networking cost. Still, I can do some performance improvement on that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned that `result.toSerializedStream()` pickles the data. So, yeah, you're right that the blocking is because of network io.

To avoid that, you can send your data in **chunks** and call `self.flush()` after every `self.write()`. Calling `flush` will write the response to the network. Since you can `await` on `flush`, until the data is written to network socket, the coroutine will pause, and the server won't block. This allows other handlers to run asynchronously.

A code sample:

```
async def get(self, name):
    ...
    response = result.toSerializedStream()

    chunk_size = 1024 * 1024 * 10 # 10 MiB

    start_byte = 0
    while True:
        chunk = response[start_byte : start_byte + chunk_size]
        if not chunk:
            break
        self.write(chunk)
        await self.flush() # wait while data is flushed to network

        start_byte += chunk_size # move start_byte forward
```

---

**Important:**

One important thing to note here is that `self.flush()` is pretty fast. If you're flushing small data to network, the `await` delay is so small that the coroutine keeps running without pause, thus blocking the server.

In the sample code above, I've set the `chunk_size` to `10 MiB`, but if your computer is fast, the `await` delay will be very, very small and the loop might run without pause until the whole data is sent.

I encourage you to increase or decrease the `chunk_size` value as per your needs.

---

**Further improvement suggestions:**

All the data is in memory. Now that your handler is asynchronous and doesn't block, if another request comes in at `ReprsHandler`, this will lead to more data storage in memory. And if more and more requests come in, then you can tell what's going to happen.

To avoid this, instead of pickling the data in memory, you can dump it to a file. Then in your handler just `open` that file and read it in chunks and send it.

Comment: Great suggestion. I really appreciate it. Working on it right away.

Answer (score 0):

OK. This question was so stupid.

I was expecting this non-blocking API to work as parallel networking, so that whole networking won't interrupt each others. And it's not what tornado is designed to be. It's non-blocking obviously, but still single threaded.